# Use PHP to execute system command with a long timeout period?

Tags: php, zip, system, archive, tar

We need to untar/unzip a very large archive file on a server that we don't have SSH access to. One of our alternative options is to execute a system command via PHP to unzip the file.

The problem is that its takes quite a while to unzip/untar the file. PHP ends up timing out before it completes.

Is there a way to make the untar command execute fully whether or not the PHP script times out or not? Like an Asynchronous execution?

Or how can you temporarily set the PHP timeout period to be extremely high so that it has enough time to finish untarring the file?

Comment: is it a linux system? because afaik, on linux, the time spent on system commands is not counted towards max_execution_time limit. maybe it is httpd that has some timeout set.

Comment: Ditto, is it a Linux system? Is it on a shared web hosting platform? Maybe you can define and run cronjobs (not uncommon in shared hosting) which would allow you to uncompress the file asynchronously. Do you need to unzip the file once or whenever a user uploads a compressed file? If it's only once, maybe you have access to a web control panel with a file manager with copmress/uncompress functions, or it might be easier to ask the server admin to unzip the file for you.

Comment: Yes, it's Linux. Rackspace Cloud Sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

What may be happening is that your client (browser) is timing out. Such a disconnection may cause the script to abort. To prevent that, you can do:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

You'll then want a second script that allows you to check the progress. One idea is to have the output of tar written to a file that your second script can check the end of to see if it's done. Another is to invoke a shell script that in turns runs tar. That shell script could either check the return code and touch a file with its results or it could create a rudimentary lock file while it is working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to output a linux command to a file so that it's continuously being updated so that another script could check the status of the command? Because from what I know, when you use `# command > output.txt` it doesn't write to the file until the command is done.

Comment: From my experience, the file is written to throughout and can be checked at anytime.

Comment: You're quite welcome for the answer. But an upvote would say it even better ;)

Comment: Yeah was just waiting to investigate other answers first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if your server configuration doesn't prevent you from modifying these values:

```
set_time_limit( 0);
ini_set( 'max_execution_time', 0);
```

See [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) and [`max_execution_time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Answer (score 0):

If the server runs on a *nix system, the nohup command might be available. ie

```
nohup tar ... >outfile.txt
```

You could then have the PHP script scan the outfile.txt until operation ends